# bash: automatic recogniton of pattern in filename and store it in variable

Tags: bash

I have a big number of images within the input folder with the names organized in the following format:

```
229e3CLpro_06I_chicont_rep1.png     mers3CLpro_BDM92386_chicont_rep1.png
229e3CLpro_5p9_chicont_rep1.png     peds3CLpro_06I_chicont_rep1.png
229e3CLpro_BDM92386_chicont_rep1.png    peds3CLpro_5p9_chicont_rep1.png
Hcov3CLpro_06I_chicont_rep1.png     peds3CLpro_BDM92386_chicont_rep1.png
Hcov3CLpro_5p9_chicont_rep1.png     sars3CLpro_06I_chicont_rep1.png
Hcov3CLpro_BDM92386_chicont_rep1.png    sars3CLpro_5p9_chicont_rep1.png
Hcov3CLpro_06I_chicont_rep1.png     sars3CLpro_BDM92386_chicont_rep1.png
mers3CLpro_5p9_chicont_rep1.png
```

I need to extract the first part (located between the first "_") of the file name and store it as an element of the list, according to the detected pattern.

In this example it should give me five elements stored in list

```
patterns=('229e3CLpro','Hcov3CLpro', 'mers3CLpro','peds3CLpro','sars3CLpro')
```

Comment: Are there always 5? Wouldn't you be better off with an array of patterns?

Comment: No, the number of patterns could be ANY, so yes you are right!  I've just edited my question.

Comment: Bash array elements are separated with spaces, not commas. `list=('one','two')` is the same as `list=( 'one,two' )`, not `list=( 'one' 'two' )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an associative array to store the patterns (needs at least bash version 4.0, released in 2009). Use parameter expansion to extract the patterns:

```bash
declare -A patterns
for f in *.png ; do
    pattern=${f%%_*}  # Remove everything after the first underscore.
    patterns[$pattern]=1
done
printf '%s\n' "${!patterns[@]}"
```

If the number of files is very high, it might be faster to extract the patterns all at once:

```bash
files=(*.png)
declare -A patterns
for f in "${files[@]%%_*}" ; do
    patterns[$f]=1
done
printf '%s\n' "${!patterns[@]}"
```

To store the patterns in a list

```bash
list=("{!patterns[@]}")
```

Comment: Maybe note that this requires Bash v4; MacOS is perpetually stuck on v3 (though you can easily install a newer version from Homebrew or etc).

Comment: @tripleee: Updated, thanks.

Comment: hello, I've just tried the first sollution and it does not work. Here is the problem. Firstly the assosiative array contains full file path with the pattern rather then the pattern, e.g /Users/test/Desktop/bazdos/img/peds3CLpro;  then the second list contains {!patterns[@]} rather then the pattern :-)

Comment: @JamesStarlight: You need to start the script from the directory where the files are. Or, use parameter expansion to remove the paths: `files=("${files[@]##*/}")`

Comment: so OK it's done. now the only problem is wih the conversion from assosiative array to list via list="{!patterns[@]}" which does not store the pattern but rather {!patterns[@]} value

Comment: @JamesStarlight, right, it should be `list=( "${!patterns[@]}" )` -- note that because `list` is an array, you need to dereference it as one or else you'll only see the first element.

Comment: Okay, thank you! just one bug related to the removing of the PATH from file name. I've just made a new topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77296684/bash-operations-on-filenames-in-the-associative-array